# Script not updating with main branch

Tags: git, github, rstudio, rscript, git-fork

I collaborate on a project where I am included as a fork on GitHub. When I pull the changes that the main branch has made, R tells me Already up to date. When I click on my script file, I notice the last modified date was behind. How do I get my script to be in sync with the main branch script? That way I'll be working on the last updated changes.

I tried git fetch origin
git checkout main
git pull origin main # pull changes from the remote main branch

It tells me Already up to date.